# What's going on in Rails' application_record.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Found this code in the Rails source code.

```
<% module_namespacing do -%>
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
<% end -%>
```

Haven't seen anything alike yet. Would someone mind to explain 
what the enclosing `module_namespacing` is doing and why it looks like a modified (because of the dashes) Rails view .erb statement?

Comment: Looking at the definition of `module_namespacing` in railties/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb, it might have something to do with weather or not your ApplicationRecord is namespaced? I.e. when you run a generator like `rails g shop/product title:string ...`

And yup, the `<% %>` just look like regular ERB! The dash in `-%>`  removes whitespace around the erb tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you looked at are just generators. You can read more about these in [official guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).

These are used, well, to generate code when you run generators :)

You can check a list of available generators with

```
bundle exec rails generate
```